# Running into 'Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Age' not found' while using predict function in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, predict

```
#Logistic Regression
glm.fit <- glm(recent_cannabis_use~.,data = drug_use_train, family = binomial)
summary(glm.fit)


predict(glm.fit, with(drug_use_train, data.frame(Gender = "Male")), type = "response")
```

Trying to find the predicted probability for recent_canabis_use for a male.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `predict(glm.fit, newdata = data.frame(Gender = "Male"))`. Using `with` in this case is not warranted, since you are not accessing any of the variables in `drug_use_train`.

Note that this assumes your formula is, upon expansion, `recent_cannabis_use ~ Gender`. If you have other variable and you want to explore only the effect of `Gender`, you will need to set (pre-calculate or make up) all other variables to some fixed value (remember how coefficients are interpreted - change in y with one unit change of x, provided everything else stays the same). See for example [this post](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html).

Comment: That makes sense. The full formula has 12 predictor variables but I am only interested in finding the prediction probability of recent_canabis_use for male as the Gender predictor variable is either male or female. Is my use of the predict() function incorrect. If so how should I go about coding this.

Comment: Also, the output in the summary for the Gender coefficient is called GenderFemale and it has an Estimate value of -0.65308.

Comment: You will need to precalculate or make up values for all but Gender independent variables. See the link in my answer.